# I want to change format of height 5'4" to 5.4, so how can i replace this format with str_replace?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change format of height 5'4" to 5.4, so how can i replace this format with str_replace

```
$str = str_replace("'", '.', $model->hight);
print_r($str);
```

This is my code it returns 5'6" => 5.6" but i want to replace " to " "(blank) also like 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = rtrim(str_replace("'",'.',$model->hight), '"');
```

Since we were discussing that there are 12 inches in a foot, and 5'6" is actually 5.5 feet, then you could use something more elaborate to calculate the decimal value of feet, such as this:

```
<?php

$str = '5\'6"';

// Get rid of the double quote on the right
$str = rtrim( $str, '"' );

// Feet will be $parts[0], and inches will be $parts[1]
$parts = explode( "'", $str );

$inches = $parts[0] * 12;

if( isset( $parts[1] ) )
    $inches += $parts[1];

$decimal = $inches / 12;

echo $decimal;
```

Keep in mind though, this calculation does not take into account if there are fractions of an inch.

Comment: Thanks @Brian this have solved my problem i got my desired result :)

Comment: Your welcome. Just so you know though, feet and inches is not like metric. 5'6" is actually 5.5 feet.

Comment: It just looks like you are trying to convert feet and inches to decimal, and there are 12 inches in a foot. For instance, there are 66 inches in 5.5 feet. Although your question was just to format the string, if you want to do an actual conversion to decimal, that would require some calculations. Let me see if I can find you something...

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace('"','',str_replace("'",'.',$model->hight));
```

Comment: Welcome Buddy :)) @shikha